# Specifications to consider when selecting a polyfuse

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, fuses, polyfuse

I am designing a power supply for a flight controller, and I am finished with the regulating and almost everything else. I want to have a polyfuse on both of my inputs, but I don't know how to pick the right one. I don't really know much about the power consumption of the application, as it can vary. But, the maximum output of the power supply is 1A. the maximum input voltage should not exceed 22.5V. I know that things to consider in such a fuse is I_trip and I_hold, and of course maximum voltage and current. Can anyone explain I_trip and I_hold to me?

Comment: You spec'd the PS output current, but not its input current. Have you determined that?

Comment: Littelfuse has a document on the selection process: [link](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/files/littelfuse/technical-resources/documents/product_brochures/ec327-e_polyfuse_ptc.pdf)

Comment: You can filter here for PTC Resettable fuses. https://www.digikey.com/products/en/circuit-protection/ptc-resettable-fuses/150?k=ptc   I've seen that the surface mount parts have lower resistance, thus develop a lower voltage drop across them, (V=IR), than the thru hole parts. I use 1206 size parts for USB fed power from a PC (like interfacing to an FTDI chip).

Comment: Beware that the current values depend very much on the environment temperature!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can anyone explain I_trip and I_hold to me?

The fuse is guaranteed not to trip if the current is less than I_hold.

The fuse is guaranteed to trip if the current is more than I_trip.

You need to choose a polyfuse with I_hold larger than your maximum load current consumption, or it may nuisance trip.

You need to choose a polyfuse with an I_trip smaller than your power supply output if you want it to trip when a fault is presented. Otherwise it may fail to trip, and cook your supply.

Comment: Better response than mine. +1.

Answer (score 3):

The I<sub>trip</sub> of a a polyfuse is the current at which the fuse 'trips'; when it goes high-impedance. Then, when it is in the high-impedance state, if the current through it goes below I<sub>hold</sub>, it will return to its low-impedance state (though not perfectly; it will still be higher resistance than it was at first).

Answer (score 2):

Most important for protection is the **interrupting capacity** in amperes and the **maximum voltage**. If you exceed either one, the fuse may not open or may be damaged. You should evaluate the worst-case fault current and make sure it cannot exceed the interrupting capacity.

Beyond that, you are interested in the worst-case current to open vs. stay closed (both minimum and maximum). Itrip and Ihold Keep in mind that there is a tolerance and both will change with temperature (and with mounting, especially for SMT parts), so you should look at the curves and not just the rating at a certain temperature.

Read the manufacturer's application notes as well as data sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Hold current is how much continuous current can flow through the PTC without tripping it. This would be the maximum operating current of your circuit.

Trip current is how much current is needed for the PTC to start heating up, which is when its internal resistance increases and current flow is reduced to protect your circuit. It is always larger than the hold current.

I would pick a trip current that protects your power supply (I_trip=1A) and then see which parts had a hold current that is high enough to suit the needs of your application.

There's a similar question with some discussion in the comments here if you need more information:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/369505/185972

Comment: " (I_trip=1A) "  OP did not state the input current to the supply, presumably where he's putting the fuse, just its output current.